# Android Dagger/Hilt providers same return value?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I need to know in my Repository whether I have internet connection or not (DB or API), so in my AppModule I use:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRepository(api: Api, dao: Dao, internetConn: Boolean) = Repository(api, dao, internetConn)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideInternetConnection(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Boolean {
       return NetworkUtils().isInternetAvailable(context)
    }
}
```

Hilt knows that the `internetConn` in the `provideRepository` params is the `fun provideInternetConnection` because of the return value (I guess).

But what if I want to create another provider with Boolean return value as well?
It's not working when I create another Singleton provider with Boolean return value.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not inject something that might change over time. Instead inject the this class that performs this check and call the function where needed. What you have now, will check for network only once while building the dependency graph.

However it is possible to get a new value is if you inject `Provider<Boolean>` instead the boolean on its own. `Provider` will always evaluate the function that is providing the instance, there fore you'll have new value each call of `isInternetAvaialbleProvider.get()` is called.